# Download npm modules only once

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, npm-install

I am packaging around 7 `meteor` applications as part of a continuous integration process. Those applications are then deployed to a server with no internet connection. There is a `npm install` step when installing a meteor app to another location. I figured I'll just run this step on the build machine where we have internet, `tar` everything, ship it, unpack it, run it on the final destination.

This works fine but looking at the logs I see that `npm` is trying to fetch the same modules for each application (so 7 times).

This occasionally fails too because I run the 7 buils in parallel and `npm` is writing to a `sqlite` DB where locking sometimes occurs.

So how I do install those `npm` modules once and for all and fetch them from a local cache (a la `maven`)?

Comment: I guess you should be able to clone the npm projects into a single folder named dependencies for exame, and then change the package.json to use the local installed file.

Comment: Looks like it's the only way to go. Just read this: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2568 It's kind of hard to believe that there is no possibility to not ask the registery :/